# _khbit() returning true when no key is pressed?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a section of code as such:

```
while (true) {
    if(_kbhit()) {
        cout << "keypressed";
        exit(1);
        }
```

for testing purposes to get the _kbhit() section working

The program takes arrow key input using GetAsyncKeyState() and in the case that the Shift key is pressed it runs this portion of code.

If i DONT press any arrow keys before i press shift to call this portion of code, then _kbhit evaluates to false as expected.

The problem is this, if i press an arrow key before i press shift to call this portion of code, "keypressed" is output even though no keys have been pressed since calling this portion of code.

Is kbhit somehow picking up the previous arrow key strokes? Do i need to clear an input buffer or something?

Comment: From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58w7c94c.aspx): "*The `_kbhit` function checks the console for **a recent keystroke**. If the function returns a nonzero value, a keystroke is **waiting in the buffer**. The program can then call `_getch` or `_getche` to get the keystroke*" (emphasis mine).

Comment: how can I clear the buffer then?

Comment: If I knew that I would have posted a proper answer. :-] I only meant to clarify that there is indeed a buffer.